# JavaScript running pretty slow in specific computer

Tags: javascript

I writing a code that take a Black & White image and check the pixels  in an specific area (with an square shape) and finally retur the sum of how many of them are balck, each pixel of the area is read in a For loop like the next example:

```
    function is_box_black_corner(x,y,width,heigth){
    var counter=0;
    for (var i=x; i<(x+width); i++){
        for (var j=y; j<(y+heigth); j++){
            if(my_isblack(i,j)==1){
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

And as you can see inside the for loop a I call a function that verifies if the specific pixel is fairly black:

```
   function my_isblack(x,y){
        var p = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
        if(p[0]<50 && p[1]<50 && p[2]<50){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

As you can imagine, this is a little bit computational expensive. but the problem is that with my computer, suddenly it got much slower than others (even with worst processors).  I already check the RAM memory and the processor and none of them were used more than 30%, and the processor before running the code is close to 0%.

And don’t know where else to look. I appreciate some help, also if somebody knows how to do this much faster it will be highly apreciated

Comment: calling `getImageData` for every pixel seems rather unnecessary when the image is always the same. Unsure if canvas has some optimization there but doubtful. Unrelated to differences between computers though.

Comment: Are you using the same browser on each? That will likely make a bigger impact than the computer, unless of of the computers is abnormally slow.

Comment: I'm using chrome for all of them. I even just unistall and install it again but didn't work

Comment: How are you measuring the time? Looking at it again, unless it is a rather large image, this should be below what one can just look at and notice the difference.

Comment: Well, the application is meant to check different types of images, but for measuring the time I am using the same image in the differents computers, and also the area to evaluate is exactly the same, with one computer it just take 1 -2 sec with a processor of 1.4 GHZ, but with the computer that has this problem (intel I7 of 2.6 GHZ) the time is pretty high (almost 1 minute)

Comment: i wonder if it is all irrelevant if you reduce the `getImageData` calls to one and reuse that data for every `my_isblack` call. Unless your images and image areas are very big i'd expect that this task should be very very fast.

Comment: I agree with @ASDFGerte, you should call `getImageData` once and then work with the data.

Comment: well, actually the images are of 300ppi (3000 x 2400 pixels) and the areas that are checked are a lot but the sum of the pixels of those areas won’t be higher than the 5 % of the total pixels of the image. so I don't know if calling for everything will be faster. I will try that anyway

Comment: "*suddenly it got much slower*" - what changed?

Comment: As another optimisation, avoid the `if` branching and use `counter += p[0]<50 & p[1]<50 & p[2]<50`

Comment: Well, I never change anything, This was an application that was already in production, and I don't know what happened (it is pretty weird) but I just realice that it was only for google chorme (maybe calling a lot of time getImageData wasn't to bad 4 day's ago) but in Mozilla it is still fairly quit. any way I actually did what @ASDFGerte suggested and is again working for all borwsers and a bit much faster. Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try wiht one call to `getImageData` as suggested by @ASDFGerte:

```
var x=10; var y=10; var width=50; var height=50;
var counter=0;
var image;
var p;   //global data

function init(){
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);      //this is just a black square

    image = ctx.getImageData(x, y, width, height);      //Load the image
    p = image.data;                                     //get the data of the image
    is_box_black_corner();
};

function is_box_black_corner(){
    for (var i=x; i<(x+width); i++){
        for (var j=y; j<(y+height); j++){
            if(my_isblack(i,j)==1){
            counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(counter);
}; 

function my_isblack(x,y){
    if(p[0]<50 && p[1]<50 && p[2]<50){  //check the global data
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
};
```